# Улучшить жуткий алгоритм

Tags: php, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Как можно улучшить данный жуткий алгоритм?
Привожу полный под для наглядности, результат должен быть точно такой же:

```
function makeBooks() {
    $CountLast = 0;
    for($i = 1; $i <= 39; $i++) {
        $Rand = rand(5, 9);
        if($i > 1)
        $PrizBooks[$i] = $PrizBooks[$i-1]+$Rand+3;
        else $PrizBooks[$i] = $Rand;

        if($i == 39 && ($PrizBooks[$i] < 385 or $PrizBooks[$i] > 389)) return false;
    }

    $PrizBooks[40] = 397;
    return $PrizBooks;
}

for($i = 0; $i < 999; $i++) {
    $PrizBooks = makeBooks();
    if($PrizBooks != false) break;
}
//Далее для наглядности

print_r($PrizBooks);

$CountPay = 0;
$CountPriz = 0;
$CountFree = 0;

$Sum = 0;
$PRB = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <= 400; $i++) {

    if(!$PRB) {
        $Sum += 333;
        $CountPay++;

        if(in_array($i, $PrizBooks)) {
            echo "<p>Призовая - ".$i;
            $PRB++;
            $CountPriz++;
        } else echo "<p>Платная - ".$i;
    } else {
        $Sum += 0;
        echo "<p>Бесплатная - ".$i.' - '.$PRB;
        if($PRB != '3') $PRB++; else $PRB = 0;
        $CountFree++;
    }
}

echo '<p>Сумма: '.$Sum;
echo '<p>Платных: '.$CountPay;
echo '<p>Призовых: '.$CountPriz;
echo '<p>Бесплатных: '.$CountFree;
```

Comment: На словах опишите, что именно оно должно делать.

Answer (score 2):

```
function makeBooks() {
   $CountLast = 0; // мне показалось, что это переменная для кол-ва элементов
   //по крайней мере она так названа :)
   for($i = 1; $i <= 39; $i++) {
      $Rand = rand(5, 9);
      if($i > 1) //непонятно зачем выполнять лишнюю проверку на каждой итерации
         $PrizBooks[$i] = $PrizBooks[$i-1]+$Rand+3;
      else $PrizBooks[$i] = $Rand; // вынести до начала цикла

      if($i == 39 && ($PrizBooks[$i] < 385 or $PrizBooks[$i] > 389)) return false; 
      //зачем проверять в цикле, все равно отработает только на последней итерации
   }

   $PrizBooks[$CountLast+1] = 397;
   return $PrizBooks;
}

for($i = 0; $i < 999; $i++) {
    $PrizBooks = makeBooks();
    if($PrizBooks != false) break;
}
```

Код в переработанном виде.

```
function makeBooks() {
   $CountLast = 39;
   //следующие 2 строки вместо первой итерации цикла
   //и это избавит нас от лишней конструкции if 
   $Rand = rand(5, 9);
   $PrizBooks[1] = $Rand;

   for($i = 2; $i <= $CountLast; $i++) {
      $Rand = rand(5, 9);
      $PrizBooks[$i] = $PrizBooks[$i-1]+$Rand+3;
   }
   //проверяем один конкретно интересующий нас элемент
   //это избавит нас еще от одной лишней конструкции if
   if($PrizBooks[$CountLast] < 385 || $PrizBooks[$CountLast] > 389) return false;

   $PrizBooks[$CountLast+1] = 397;
   return $PrizBooks;
}

for($i = 0; $i < 999; $i++) {
   $PrizBooks = makeBooks();
   if($PrizBooks != false) break;
}
```

Итого -1 итерация и на 78 проверок меньше (убраны if из цикла).

И еще одна мысля стукнула. Может вам надо так?

```
function makeBooks() {
   $CountLast = 39;
   $Rand = rand(5, 9);
   $PrizBooks[0] = $Rand;
   for($i = 1; $i < $CountLast-1; $i++) {
      //$min=$PrizBooks[$i-1]+1;//можно выбрать минимум на 1 больше предшественника

      //но я посоветую приращивать минимум побыстрее
      //чтоб исключить возможность получить "медленный прирост", типа 5,6,8,9...
      $min=round(($PrizBooks[$i-1]+$CountLast*10+5)/2)

      $max=10*$CountLast+9;//"верхний порог" стремится к 379
      $Rand = rand($min, $max);
      $PrizBooks[$i] = $Rand;
   }
   //а 39-й элемент "загоним в рамки" от 385 до 389
   $Rand = rand(($CountLast-1)*10+5, ($CountLast-1)*10+9);            
   $PrizBooks[$CountLast-1] = $Rand;//напомню 1-й элемент с ключем 0, 
   //поэтому 39-й с ключем 38
   $PrizBooks[$CountLast] = 397;
   return $PrizBooks;
}

$PrizBooks = makeBooks();
```

Так желаемый массив получится с первой попытки. Хотя алгоритм усложнился, но теперь не нужно ждать пока он на n-ном выполнении вернет желаемый массив.

А если все загнать в пределы "порогов", то:

```
function makeBooks() {
   for($i=0;$i<=39;$i++){
      $PrizBooks[$i] = $Rand = rand($i*10+5, $i*10+9);//1-ая итерация от 5 до 9, а последняя от 395 до 399
      //$PrizBooks[$i] = $Rand = rand($i*10+1, $i*10+10); //1-ая итерация от 1 до 10, а последняя от 390 до 400
   }
   return $PrizBooks;
}
```

Comment: а вы знаете чем `or` отличаеться от `||`

Comment: Спасибо за замечания :)

Comment: Я с пхп так - постольку поскольку. Да лучше `||`. Не знал об этой заморочке.